# Python: file closed inside with block

Tags: python

I'm doing some file processing on the downloaded file. I'm calling a function inside a `with` block, which is doing some file processing and is writing the results to a temporary file. But after returning from the function, my files are closed and I get `ValueError: seek of closed file`.
Can someone explain to me why the temporary files are closed while still being inside the `with` block?

```
def run(ftp_file):
    with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as src, tempfile.TemporaryFile() as dest:
        for line in ftp_file.readlines():
            # some file cleansing here
            src.write(line)

        src.seek(0)
        process_file1(src, dest)

        assert src.closed is True
        assert dest.closed is True

        dest.seek(0)  # raises ValueError: seek of closed file


def process_file1(src, dest):
    """ Write some columns """
    fieldnames = ['f1', 'f2']
    reader = csv.DictReader(io.TextIOWrapper(src))
    writer = csv.DictWriter(io.TextIOWrapper(dest, write_through=True), fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in reader:
        writer.writerow({col: row[col] for col in fieldnames})
```

Comment: `process_file2(src, dest)` and `process_file2` closes `dest`?

Comment: @MikeMüller process_file2 is similar to process_file1, no there are no close there. And it doesn't called here. I removed it from the code, not to confuse other.

Comment: If your assertions pass, then you already know it is closed thus the error. If one of your assertion fails, it throw an assertion error, and then the context manager will handle your resources and close it. If you reach the line, it is because the resource is closed. Check what is going on in `process_file1`, the key must be there

Comment: @jlandercy I've added asserts just for illustration. I know smth going on in function. If I could figure out what exactly I wouldn't ask a question :)

Comment: Just a supposition: What if your writer closes its file descriptor when garbage collected. When you exited from the function, writer will be managed by the garbage collector because it becomes out of scope. Then it may close the underlying resources. Does it happen if the code embedded in your function lives in the context manager?

Comment: We could avoid a good amount of "what if?" back-and-forth if there was a [mcve] here.

Comment: @Kevin True! But for this to work I must also include csv file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Problem

The problem is `io.TextIOWrapper`:

```
with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as fobj:
    print(fobj.closed)
    io.TextIOWrapper(fobj)
    print(fobj.closed)
```

Output:

```
False
True
```

### Solution

Change:

```
with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as src, tempfile.TemporaryFile() as dest:
```

to:

```
with io.TextIOWrapper(tempfile.TemporaryFile()) as src, \
     io.TextIOWrapper(tempfile.TemporaryFile()) as dest:
```

So you only create one file object for `scr` and `dest` respectively.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how can I configure `TextIOWrapper` not to close the file?

Comment: sadly no, I must have access to file opened as bytes.